# Admob in Titanium can't build

Tags: titanium, admob, appcelerator

Maybe i'm just being stupid, or perhaps Titanium has moved on, but i'm trying to run your command in Terminal and i get an error:

python: can't open file 'build.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The file I download have this name: masuidrive-TiAdMob4iPhone-2a6fe97.zip

I cant find 'jp.masuidrive.ti.admob-0.1.zip' anywhere

I trie to rename it and put it on module folder but nothing happens.

any help

Thanks

Comment: is this TiMobile or TiDesktop?

Comment: so you already extracted the `module` into `/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium` directory? Did you modify your `tiapp.xml` to look `<modules><module version="0.x.x">MODULE NAME</module></modules>`?

Answer (score 0):

With Titanium its always worth restarting everything, *deleting your build folder* and any other voodoo you can think of before giving up, esp when messing with modules. That error looks somewhat familiar.